# embed YOUTUBE video - turn off autoplay

Tags: jquery, html, video, youtube

I'm getting crazy about embed youtube video, I want to disable autoplay on pageload (firefox / chrome) !

for example:

```
<iframe id="movie" width="100%" height="517" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ctxUB40iaAw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I trying adding:

&autopla=0 / autoplay = false

but Its not working in firefox!

Video is hidden and autoplaying ON click, so it must be disabled on pageload.

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't due to any FF addon?.... `autoplaying ON click` Provide relevant code btw

Comment: I dont have any addon in FF

Comment: So your click handler is maybe triggered in some way or you bind it incorrectly. And have you same issue on other browsers? Your question suggests it is only on FF, but...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to use `autostart="false"`;
It is an attribute for HTML5`<video>` tag.

Comment: OP isn't using `video` tag

Comment: I dont know how, but this work in Firefox and Chrom... thx!

Comment: @NoName so you did use html5 video tag?? Next time write your question a bit better please.

Comment: @NoName That must be a joke, right?!  How do you use it, can ou share it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not append `&autoplay=0` but `?autoplay=0`.
Url: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/ctxUB40iaAw?autoplay=0` works fine to me on firefox. It does not autoplay.

If that does not turn out good you can also use the Javascript API for youtube iframes.
Using `player.stopVideo();` you can make sure that each video stops playing after load. See more details for the API [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: But does it autoplay if you don't add any param in url???

Comment: @A.Wolff no.. good point there. But still `&` is wrong, since autoplay is the first param